# Given a set of independence relations, how can I find a set of vectors satisfying them?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, representation-theory, matroids

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. The problem is to find a set of vectors $W$ such that there exists some bijection $f:V \to W$ and for all $a \in V$, we have $f(a)$ is not a linear combination of $f(N(a))$, the image of its neighbors.

For a specific example, consider the graph $K_{2,2,2}$, the 1-skeleton of the octahedron. I can obviously compute a set by hand, but this seems like something that has been done before so I'm looking for references. I'm also interested in a projective version of this question.

Thanks for your help and let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: As your question stands, could you not just pick $n(G)$ linearly independent vectors? Or are there other conditions you would like to impose, like something on the dimensionality of the vectors?

Comment: A natural additional condition is that for each vertex $v$ the set $\{v\} \cup N(v)$ forms a _maximal_ independent set. My answer below uses this additional condition and classifies those graphs for which such a vector representation can be found.

Answer (score 1):

A natural additional condition is that for each vertex $v$ the set $\{v\} \cup N(v)$ forms a *maximal* independent set. Let $\Delta = \Delta(G)$ be the [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) whose facets are the sets $\{v\} \cup N(v)$.

Note that in general $\Delta(G)$ is neither the [independence complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex#Independence_complex) of $G$ nor the [matroid independence complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets) of $G$.

Now, our new simplicial complex $\Delta$ is representable by a collection of vectors in some vector space if and only if $\Delta$ is the matroid independence complex of *some* [realizable matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_representation). In particular, all facets of $\Delta$ must have the same size, which implies that $G$ must be $r$-regular.

Taking $G$ to be the 1-skeleton of the octohedron, $\Delta(G)$ is the matroid independence complex of the [uniform matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_matroid) $U_{5,6}$ which explains why you were able to find such a representation in this case. More generally, if $G$ is the 1-skeleton of the $n$-dimensional cross polytope then $\Delta(G)$ is isomorphic to the matroid independence complex of $U_{2n-1, 2n}$.